# Как сделать xsd валидацию для такого куска хмл?

Tags: xml, xsd

Всем привет! 
Нужно сделать хsd валидацию на такой хмл:

```
<Info>
<Text key="some_date" value="25.07.2017"/>
<Text key="some_code" value="1111111"/>
<Text key="some_number" value="1111111"/>
</Info>
```

Суть заключается в том что в "Info" может быть произвольное кол. тегов "Text", но если не будет в атрибутах: some_date, some_code, some_number то не валидно и так же нужно ставить валидацию на атрибут value(например формат даты должен передаваться через точку). Возможно не совсем понятно, приведу пример что корректно, а что нет.

Корректно:

1.

```
<Info>
<Text key="some_date" value="25.07.2017"/>
<Text key="some_code" value="1111111"/>
<Text key="some_number" value="1111111"/>
</Info>
```

2.

```
<Info>
<Text key="some_code" value="1111111"/>
<Text key="some_number" value="1111111"/>
<Text key="some_date" value="25.07.2017"/>
</Info>
```

3.

```
<Info>
<Text key="some_code" value="1111111"/>
<Text key="some_number" value="1111111"/>
<Text key="some_date2" value="25.07.2017"/>
<Text key="some_date3" value="25.07.2017"/>
<Text key="some_date" value="25.07.2017"/>
</Info>
```

Не корректно:

1.

```
<Info>
<Text key="some_date" value="25.07.2017"/>
<Text key="some_code" value="1111111"/>
</Info>
```

2.

```
<Info>
<Text key="some_date" value="25-07-2017"/>
<Text key="some_code" value="1111111"/>
<Text key="some_number" value="1111111"/>
</Info>
```

3.

```
<Info>
<Text key="some_date1" value="25.07.2017"/>
<Text key="some_code1" value="1111111"/>
<Text key="some_number1" value="1111111"/>
</Info>
```

Answer (score 0):

В первом приближении, схема будет такой:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:simpleType name="key">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="some_date\d*|some_code\d*|some_number\d*"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="value">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="\d+|\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}"></xs:pattern>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:element name="Info">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="3" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Text">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="key" type="key" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="value" type="value" use="required" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Проверку этой схемой проходит последний пример (который должен быть некорректным).

Если нужны точные совпадениия `some_date`, `some_code`, `some_number`, то можно использовать такое определение:

```
<xs:simpleType name="key">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="some_date"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="some_code"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="some_number"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Но тогда третий из корректных примеров не подпадает под него. Уточните требования.

Я использовал в схеме `minOccurs="3"`. Это помогает отловить первый из некорректных примеров. Но, конечно, это не совсем правильно.

---

Уточню.

XmlSchema **запрещает** определять элементы с одним и тем же именем, но разных типов. То есть **невозможно** определить правила валидирования, которые вы хотите.

Наиболее правильный вариант, определить элементы с разными именами:

```
<Info>
  <Date value="25.07.2017"/>
  <Code value="1111111"/>
  <Number value="1111111"/>
</Info>
```

Вот тут уже можно написать желаемую валидацию.

Comment: это не сработает так как нет проверки по  key и value то есть так будет не корректно, но хсд покажет что все ок:
*<Info>
<Text key="some_date" value="1111"/>
<Text key="some_date" value="1111"/>
<Text key="some_date" value="1111"/>
<Text key="some_date" value="1111"/>
</Info>*

так как например "some_date"  относится к возможным значениям: some_date\d*|some_code\d*|some_number\d*, но  нет в хмл some_code и some_number. тоже самое касается и value.

Comment: @UDAnton - я знаю, что эта схема валидирует лишь часть хотелок. Боюсь, что лучше никто не предложит. В версии XmlSchema 2.0 можно сделать больше проверок.